# My Angular code not working in Plunker

Tags: angularjs, plunker

Added ng-app. But still it shows as plain text instead of the result. What's missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.45" 
        src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.45/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{ 67 / 23 }}
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the angular library given to you by Plunker doesn't work.

Simply replace the script element with the google-provided version, and you're away.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```